# REPEATABLE READ and READ UNCOMMITTED isolation levels for transactions

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions

Could someone please help explain what REPEATABLE READ and READ UNCOMMITTED is for the isolation levels for transactions and the comparison between these and READ COMMITTED and SERIALIZABLE?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2005/05-nov/o65asktom-082389.html

Comment: Cheers @DaveCosta I was struggling to find some information on this.